# java jdk 11, where is the jre folder?

Tags: java, jdk, tomcat

I was installing tomcat 9 and when I have to browse for the *jre* folder, I am not able to find it! where is it?

Comment: What Java JDK did you install exactly and how? There's e.g. OpenJDK from the Ubuntu repos and Oracle's JDK.

Comment: I installed JDK 11 and using downloaded tomcat9! so in most tutorials, it shows instructions for older versions for java spring!

Comment: That did not answer the question I asked in my comment. Oracle's JDK 11 from their website or a PPA, or OpenJDK from the Ubuntu repos? Which one did you install and how?

Comment: I went to oracle's website!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52584888/4464570

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JRE and JavaFX is not included in JDK 11.
See the **Important Changes and Information** in [Release note](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html)

Comment: Please mark as correct answer if it solved your problem

Comment: JRE isn't included with Oracle's JDK. But if you install OpenJDK11 from Ubuntu's repository it will automatically install JRE as well. @Claudia hasn't clarified which JDK she is using. So it is hard to tell whether she has JRE or not.

Comment: I am using JDK 11!

Comment: While this would explain *why* the OP can not find a JRE folder, if she is actually using Oracle's version of JDK 11, it does not really solve the resulting problem of making sure that there will be such a folder and locating it.

Comment: @ClaudiaBringas are you using OpenJRE/OpenJDK or Oracle's JDK?  They differ greatly, and your answer determines whether this answer actually *is* an answer or not.

Comment: I am not using Ubuntu open JDK11.